# Perl: I/O Redirection with IPC::Run

Tags: perl, io, openssl, ipc

Using [IPC::Run](http://search.cpan.org/~toddr/IPC-Run-0.92/lib/IPC/Run.pm) trying to imitate the following is not producing the desired affect for me at this time. Unfortunately I am not familiar enough with I/) redirection with `IPC::Run` to solve for myself and I will need to employ the great knowledge-base of SO.

**Command I am imitating**

```
echo | openssl s_client -connect google.com:443 2>/dev/null |openssl x509
```

This will display the SSL certificate retrieved from a remote server with `openssl`. The key to it working right is the `2>/dev/null` pump of `stderr` to /dev/null as `openssl` will use `stderr` to output additional information (not really error) and without this the command being piped into `openssl x509` will fail.

Here is where `IPC::Run` come in. I need to use this functionality of `openssl` in perl using `IPC::Run` as that is what all my other functions are using currently. Unfortunately using `IPC::Run` in the manner in which I do shell redirects such as `2>/dev/null` do not work as a shell is not evoked, to run the command and adding `2>/dev/null` will simply append that as an argument to the `openssl` call.

Currently I have the following, which would work without the pesky `stderr` issue. Also there is no agreement to the `openssl` command to suppress it.

```
use IPC::Run qw( run );    
my ( $out, $err );
    my @cmd  = qw(echo);                                            
    my @cmd2 = qw(openssl s_client -connect google.com:443:443);     
    my @cmd3 = qw(openssl x509);                                   
    run \@cmd, "|", \@cmd2, "|", \@cmd3, \$out, \$err;                        
    if ( $err ne '' ) {                                              
        print $err;
    }
    else {
        print "$out\n";
    }
```

So basically I need to discard `stderr` for @cmd2 which is typically done with,

```
run \@cmd, \$in, \$out, \undef;
```

but with the | present as `stdin` for @cmd3 I can not redirect `stderr` from @cmd2 as the descriptors for `stderr` is after that for `stdout`. I figure there has to be a way to suppress 'stderr' using this module between two pipe, but I have not figured it out yet, and am not familiar with the I/O operations enough to get this quickly. Anyone got a suggestion for doing this from experience?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 'echo' not needed. If you just want to close the connection opened by s_client use a closed stdin.
Also in your example you connect to google.com:443:443 which is propable one :443 too much.
The following works for me

```
use IPC::Run 'run';

my @cmd1 = qw(openssl s_client -connect google.com:443);
my @cmd2 = qw(openssl x509);

my $stdout = my $stderr = '';
run \@cmd1, '<', \undef, '|', \@cmd2, '2>', \$stderr, '>', \$stdout;
print $stdout;
```